# MPNS Push Notification Channel never returns HTTPS URI

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mpns

I'm trying to set up an authenticated push notification channel for Windows Phone 8 using MPNS.

I'm creating an `HttpNotificationChannel` with `new HttpNotificationChannel( ChannelName, ServiceName );`, which, to my understanding, should result in getting an `https://` channel URI.

But the channel URI that is assigned to the channel will always be `http://`.

What do I have to do to get the `https://` channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding or removing the service name from the `HttpNotificationChannel` construction, the URI prefix will not always be changed. *Why* that is is unclear.

What helps is to uninstall the app and reboot the device. Afterwards the channel URI will have the correct prefix, depending on if a service name was provided.